# XNA 4 VertexPositionTexture triangleStrip sporadically disappearing

Tags: xna-4.0, vertex-buffer

I am drawing a traingleStrip using VertexPositionTexture and BasicEffect that extends from the first person perspective of the screen out a certain distance on the Z axis. 
In a loop I pass start and end vectors to this code to create my vertices.

```
    public VertexPositionTexture[] vertices = new VertexPositionTexture[4];
    private int xPos = 4;

    public waypointLineSegment(Vector3 startPoint, Vector3 endPoint)
    {
        this.texture = texture1;
        vertices[0].Position = new Vector3(endPoint.X - xPos, endPoint.Y, endPoint.Z); //Upper Left Point
        vertices[0].TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(0, 1);
        vertices[1].Position = new Vector3(startPoint.X - xPos, endPoint.Y, startPoint.Z); //Lower Left point
        vertices[1].TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(0, 0);
        vertices[2].Position = new Vector3(endPoint.X + xPos, endPoint.Y, endPoint.Z); //Upper Right Point
        vertices[2].TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(1, 1);
        vertices[3].Position = new Vector3(startPoint.X + xPos, endPoint.Y, startPoint.Z); //Lower Right Point
        vertices[3].TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(1, 0);
    }
```

I initialize like this:

```
protected override void Initialize()
{
    graphics.GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = RasterizerState.CullNone;
    basicEffect = new BasicEffect(graphics.GraphicsDevice);
    base.Initialize();
}
```

I render the plane in this way:

```
Vector3 transformedReference = Vector3.Transform(new Vector3(0, 0, 10), aRotationInt);
Vector3 cameraLookat = firstPersonVector + transformedReference;
view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(firstPersonVector, cameraLookat, Vector3.Up);

basicEffect.View = view;
foreach (EffectPass pass in basicEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
{
     pass.Apply();
     graphics.GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleStrip, allVertices, 0, 2);
}
```

This works great. But, when I apply a rotation to the view, the strip will disappear every once in a while. Then it will reappear with a single degree of more or less rotation applied.

I cannot find a pattern. It might happen at 37 degrees or 315 etc. I have set the GraphicsDevice RasterizerState to CullMode.None. Can anyone help?:

Comment: You are encountering aliasing issues. At a certain angle when its edge is facing the camera your strip will disappear.

Comment: What should I do? The problem persists whether or not I set graphics.PreferMultiSampling = true;

Comment: Give the strip a small thickness. BTW multisample will not fix this, when the strip is exactly edge on; No matter the subpixel chosen for sampling, the intersection is still 0.

Comment: I will try that. I was hoping to avoid it since it will a lot more manual drawing but it sounds like the answer.

Comment: You can use a simple geometry shader which generates vertices at a small offset along the local surface normal. That way you can reuse the shader.

Comment: Everything I read says the XNA does not support geometry shaders. Any other way to do this?